# SIlverlight 3 ClientHttp vs BrowserHttp stack: no cross domain policy means no gzip for Silverlight

Tags: support, status-completed, api

<strike>I notice that even if I send `accept-encoding=gzip` the response does not seem to be compressed.</strike> ( it is late and i was conflating 'accept' with 'accept-encoding')

<strike>Should we expect, in the 1.0 timeframe to be getting gzipped responses and therefore expect to   need to set that header?</strike>

I would like to know in order to make some design decisions.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Kevin, here is some data for consideration in response to your response.

From **XMLHttpRequest**

```
GET /0.8/badges?key=NLIXkFCt8Eu-oq1Mzw3pgg&jsonp=jsonp1276425901091 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
Referer: http://soapi.info/code/js/stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __qca=P0-473080984-1269917382233; usr=t=puUW6SFMp0Sx&s=IgtyKFGnWUKz; __utmz=140029553.1276424207.947.185.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=sztupy%20codeproject; __utma=140029553.1848660693.1269917382.1276411100.1276424207.947; __utmc=140029553


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2010 11:17:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-RateLimit-Max: 10000
X-RateLimit-Current: 9223
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Length: 5918

[binary data]
```

From **Silverlight ClientHttpRequest** which does not actually allow setting the accept-encoding header and does *not* support gzip.

```
GET /0.8/users/242897/comments/160173?key=qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: api.stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2010 11:17:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-RateLimit-Max: 10000
X-RateLimit-Current: 9232
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Length: 2430

{
  "total": 3,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "comments": [
```

I was mistaken in the details of my initial report as I was setting the 'accept' header, not accept-encoding (this is not supported by silverlight).

But the end result is that I am *not* sending (not able to send) 'accept-encoding=gzip' and I *am* getting uncompressed responses from the server. This, while ultimately not what we want, is the correct result.

The issue I am having is that using the browser stack in silverlight will enable gzip but is crippled in every other area and is sub-optimal to say the least.

Using the .net stack enables, amongst other critical functionality, parsing of the rate limit headers. This is a known issue in SL3 and is not to change. I am not sure about SL4, I haven't dug deep enough yet.

And regarding 'you can't get a response that isn't compressed; you can only choose between gzip & deflate' - the sessions above disagree, and rightly so.

If the server was to disregard accept-encoding headers and force compression it would simply 'break the internet'.

So I guess we can chalk this question up as a head's up that SL3 clients are likely to be pulling text.

I am going to spend (likely waste) some time working with the browser stack and try to get an acceptable implementation going but I don't have high hopes.

**MO'N'BETTA INFO**

Groggy me, making a lot of noise but saying little: The reason that I have to use the ClientHttp stack is that the api has no crossdomain policy file and the BrowserHttp stack fails.

So, I guess the question can evolve to "Is there a reason that a cross domain policy file is not present?"

Silverlight thinks that flash's crossdomain.xml format is yummy.

**`crossdomain.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

ClientHttpWebRequest does **NOT** request nor accept compressed response. Note the 'Transforms' UI.

**XHR**

[image]

**ClientHttpWebRequest**

[image]

Comment: http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/clientaccesspolicy.xml - Silverlight's not really my bag, but is something about that incorrect/insufficient?

Comment: @Kevin - r.e. clientaccesspolicy.xml: apparently not, but silverlight does like flash crossdomain.xml files. See question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to double-check<sup>*</sup> this.

Everything I get back from the API is definitely gzip compressed.

For that matter, you can't get a response that isn't compressed; you can only choose between gzip & deflate.  Default is gzip.

The API always sets the `Content-Encoding` response header, so you might be the victim of your library decompressing the response for you.

<sub>*Triple-checked: I ran our test cases without setting `Accept-Encoding` but leaving the gzip decompression code in.</sub>

---

Bare minimum request using the world's worst stackoverflow clone (w/ gzip off):

Header:

```
GET http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/242897/comments/160173?sort=votes&order=desc&page=1&pagesize=30&key=iv1qWOxcwkaKg53RJIXh-A HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WorldsWorstStackOverflowClone
Host: api.stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2010 13:44:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-RateLimit-Max: 10000
X-RateLimit-Current: 9473
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Length: 625

[gzip'd byte stream]
```

---

This is a quite old question, but just to be 100% clear.

The API **always** responds with gzip'd content.

There are cross policy domain files on the API, StackAuth, and sstatic for Flash **and** Silverlight.

Comment: it is in the late hours for me and my initial report was specious but there may be something in the update to consider.

Comment: @code poet - I'm like 99% sure that Siverlight is just hiding its handling of the `Content-Encoding` header from you, we jump through some hoops to **never** return uncompressed content.  Send me the code and I'll investigate to be sure.

Comment: Kevin, the headers are from fiddler.

Comment: And PLEASE, do not succeed in your efforts to ignore internet standards by forcing gzip. That would simply be all kinds of wrong on all kinds of levels and not what I would expect from the Stack Overflow team.

Comment: @code poet - yeah... you're gonna have to accept gzip compressed content.  We're not compromising on that, its 2010, the future is now, etc. etc.  Technically, we should be 406'ing non-compressed requests; but that breaks tons of proxies (we found this out the hard way) so we do something non-standard to work around others who are breaking standards.  There's no perfect solution.  Also - I think I might know what's causing this gzip problem, will try and have a fix out for it tomorrow evening.  No promises on the time-frame, and I would still like your code to test with.

Comment: I am not sure you are picking up what I am putting down: Silverlight ClientHttp stack does not support gzip. That is the code we are talking about here. But Soapi is here: https://bitpusher@bitbucket.org/bitpusher/soapi - I am pushing on documentation and last minute adjustments but I generally only push compilable code. Open the vs9 solution - I haven't reviewed the vs10 solution in the last few hours and since I am linking files I promise it is broken.  Soapi.SL.Tests is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you force gzip you will break Silverlight 3 (and possibly 4) clients. Unless there is a 'strict in what you issue, relaxed in what you accept' feature in the SL stack that I haven't tested. When I get a moment I will build a server that only pushes gzip and see how the SL stack handles it.

Comment: @code poet - behavior is "honor accept-encoding, but if omitted assume gzip".  Either way a `Content-Encoding` is set accordingly.

Comment: So, silverlight is sending `accept-encoding = identity` which equates to no encoding and apparently the servers are honoring it. Which is a good thing. If it stops, a lot of (valuable) hours of development time for an unknown number of devoted SO aficionado will be lost.